# Problem adding minutes with plusMinutes

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm trying to add some minutes to a date using plusMinutes, but it just doesn't add anything at all:

Here's the code:

```
    String currentDate ;
    SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    Date date1= null;
    DateTime dt;

    currentDate ="27/12/2010 11:29" ;

    try {
           date1= myFormat.parse(currentDate);

        } catch (ParseException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
    dt = new DateTime(date1);
    dt.plusMinutes(30);
```

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Now use [`LocalDateTime::plusMinutes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plusMinutes-long-) as shown in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49162285/642706) below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) says

> Returns a copy of this datetime plus the specified number of millis.

so

do something like

```
dt = new DateTime(date1);
dt = dt.plusMinutes(30);
System.out.println(""+dt);
```

Comment: @ant18 I am surprised by 3 favorite to this Q. :)

Comment: This is really Joda's foolish implementation. If I use plusMinutes in that object. It of course should affect the object itself! :@

Answer (score 3):

Beauty of joda is that most of their classes are immutable like String in Java. Update operations doesn't change the original object. So [**plusMinutes(...)**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-1.6/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusMinutes%28int%29) returns a **new copy of the DateTime** with the minutes added which you can assign to a new variable as shown below.

```
DateTime newDt=dt.plusMinites(30);
System.out.println(newDt);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `dt = dt.plusMinutes(30);`

`plusMinutes` returns a calculated dateTime. It does not modify the dateTime it is called on.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "27/12/2010 11:29" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm" )
).plusMinutes( 30 )
```

> 2010-12-27T11:59

Tip: If you intended this to be a moment, a specific point on the timeline, apply the context of a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

## java.time

Your Question uses the troublesome old date-time classes from the earliest versions of Java, and your Question uses the Joda-Time project which is now in maintenance mode. Both have been supplanted by the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Your string input lacks an indicator of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). So parse as a [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "27/12/2010 11:29" , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2010-12-27T11:29

Note that you do *not* have an actual moment, this is *not* a specific point on the timeline. This is only a vague idea about *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours. To determine an actual moment, place this in the context of a time zone (or offset): `ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) ;`.

Add your minutes.

```
LocalDateTime later = ldt.plusMinutes( 30 ) ;
```

> later.toString(): 2010-12-27T11:59

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).